# Audio playback issue with video.js on some browsers - Only one channel playing for multi-channel audio

Tags: html, google-chrome, audio, video.js

I am facing an audio playback issue with video.js when attempting to play a video that contains multiple audio channels (C, L, R, Ls, Rs, LFE). The problem specifically occurs on mobile browsers, where only one channel (mainly a channel with very low vocals) is being played as the output. However, on PC, all channels are outputting simultaneously, and the audio is perfect.

I have tested with other audio files that have 2 channels (or mono), and they play as expected on all browsers, including mobile. It seems to be an issue specifically related to multi-channel audio playback on mobile browsers using video.js.